# table cell size changes when popping up images using CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a HTML/CSS page -- no javascript -- where I'm attempting to display a table/grid of thumbnail images.  When the user hovers the mouse over one of the image, I'd like the full-size image to be shown.

I created a fiddle to show where I'm at:  https://jsfiddle.net/StephaneCharette/y50rn9g4/

The problem I don't know how to solve:  when the popup image is shown, the **height** of the row is modified which pushes everything down.

I've managed to fix the width of each cell using `table-layout:fixed;` and then specifying a width for both the table and each cell in the first row.  (Though I'm not certain I did that correctly.)  But how do I prevent the height from changing?

```css
table, th, td
{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
table
{
  border-collapse:collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 1000px; // table-layout fixed seems to only works if you then give it a width
}
.thumb
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 320px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative; // need to specify 'position' to use z-index
  z-index: 0;
}
.thumb:hover
{
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 999;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 10em;">th1</th>
    <th style="width: 330px;">th2</th>
    <th style="width: 330px;">th3</th>
    <th style="width: 330px;">th4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>row1</th>
    <td>some example text before the image <img class="thumb" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Alice_%28apple%29.jpg" /></td>
    <td><img class="thumb" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Ambrosia_apples_2017_A3.jpg" />some example text after the image</td>
    <td><img class="thumb" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Malus-Ananasrenette.jpg" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>row2</th>
    <td><img class="thumb" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Arkansas_Black_apples_%28cropped%29.jpg" /></td>
    <td><img class="thumb" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Aroma.jpg" /></td>
    <td><img class="thumb" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Malus-Boskoop_organic.jpg" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: When i hover the first image of second row, the image it's bigger but doesn't push the other images, this is what you want?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou I want the table cells to not resize.  Neither the width, nor the height.  In this fiddle there are only 2 rows, so it doesn't look too bad, but in my real world situation there are many rows and I'd like the grid to stay put.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just replace this style in your css**

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0.5em;
    position: relative;
}

.thumb:hover {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 999;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `position:absolute` to `.thumb:hover`
https://jsfiddle.net/0pmjsybr/

Answer (score 0):

Check my jsfiddle code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/th3on24b/). Also on `hover` the images get full width and height which looks bad and covers everything else.I have set on `hover`, image width to `600px`.

```
 .thumb:hover => width: 600px;
```